# OS upgrade forced in steps

Tags: do-release-upgrade, release-management

Is it by design that Ubuntu 18.04 will not upgrade to 20.10 immediately?

I set my os update setting to ‘normal’ which means it will match any OS upgrade, not just lts.

Yet, the OS update for 18.04 will go to 20.04 and not 20.10 version.

I expect it to be possible to upgrade to latest.

Comment: What have you researched so far and have you looked at [this reference](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-to-ubuntu-20-10)

Comment: Alternatively, you can perform a fresh installation of 20.10. Note that 20.04 and 18.04 are LTS versions (each supported for 5 years from their initial release), whereas 20.10 will only be supported for 9 months

Comment: Exactly when did you install Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. we have TWO chains.

- every 6 months. This is jumping from every OS to the next. This is for the desktop user that likes to keep up to date (well... we do at some point lag behind 6 months ;) )
- every 2 years. This is jumping LTS to LTS. This is to cater companies that use Ubuntu as a server but also users that want a stable system that is kept up with security but do not need newer software.

There is one thing to note that you are probably not aware of: 20.04 inherits the hardware stack from 20.10 as soon as 20.04.1 is released (and it has).

You can also always re-install. That (with some setup from you) is far easier and quicker.

Comment: I understand, I just wondered if I can't just jump cross chain. I can go from 20.04.1 to 20.10, so why not from 18.04 to 20.10 ?

Comment: because 20.04 -> 20.10 follows the 1st chain and 18.04->20.10 does not follow any of the 2. As of JULY 2020 you can go 18.04 -> 20.04.1. And 20.04.1 is 20.04 with the hardware stack from 20.10 (20.04.2 is 20.04 with the hardware stack from 20.10 + 21.04)

Comment: You can TRY to "just jump cross chain". It's your system. The instructions for how to jump are widely available. However, we do not test jumping, and we do not provide support for jumpers when they encounter problems. You will almost certainly encounter problems: 2.5 years is an enormous leap, and a lot has changed.

Comment: @user535733 Fair enough... not jumping then. Unfortunately, that is far from reliable as well. `grub_file_filters not found.` and un-bootable system. Will try a rescue USB now.